# Any examples how to use timestamp parameter in Jasper IReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Can anyone help me how to use timestamp parameter in **Jasper IReport**?
I'm using this format new `java.sql.Timestamp(2013,2,26,3,15,0,0)` but it throws error in the query window but when I pass the parameter via prompt it shows the time in the following format

> 26-02-13 3:26 AM

JRXML for reference:

`

Comment: show your code..........

Comment: `<parameter name="From_Date" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
   <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
   <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.sql.Timestamp(2010,7,6,0,0,0,0)]]></defaultValueExpression>
  </parameter>`

Comment: are you passing the time stamp value as parameter from java class

Comment: yeah if i pass the parameter from java it shows no report. if pass it on ireport prompt i get the report displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

Inside java class

```
   Map parameters = new HashMap();
   parameters.put("From_Date",Timestamp.valueOf("2005-06-01 00:00:00.000000"));
   JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, parameters,cn);
```

In jrxml

```
<parameter name="From_Date" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
```

in detail section of jrxml

```
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="974661e4-5ac1-4ab2-b933-27f132f4498b" x="70" y="35" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{From_Date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

Comment: No report is been displayed. I'm getting blank exports from jasper.

Comment: that's because you are not connected to any db or if there returns empty returns for your query

Comment: The report works very well in ireport with all query. When i pass the value from it fails

Comment: Please check the above JRXML. I dont find issue with JRXML. The problem is how do we pass the value from Java. it fails with usual format

Comment: are you using oracle database

Comment: Nope Mysql. can you add the session to chat . I'm not able to do it

Comment: yeah. any idea with the JRXML

Comment: Can't you add it to chat or give me gtalk id